# strange behaviour on changing listview backgroundcolor

Tags: android, listview, colors, background, selection

Please help me with a listview .When i click on an item in  listview ,I want to highlight the clicked item  by changing  the background color ,but on clicking the list item background color changes for more than one  item .It doesn't happen all the time but randomly.I researched a lot on this topic ,especially on SO and nothing seems to work with me.

And I also want that changed color to persist throughout the task.i.e.the selected item should remain highlighted even if i come back to the Activity after switching  between activities.

I save the position to static ArrayList SELECTEDLIST in the Onclick event .
In GetView method i check if the position is contained in the SELECTEDLIST,and change background accordingly.

```
  for(String selected:TempVar.SELECTEDLIST){
        if(Integer.toString(position).equals(selected))

             {
               vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg_hover);
             }
        else
            {
                vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg);
            }
        }
```

If i reload the activity only the last selected item has changed background colour. But the ArrayList Selected List contains all of the selected listitem positions.Is there anything i am  missing ??

EDIT

```
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_single_item, null);


        final TextView textID=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.menu_single_item_id);
        final TextView textName=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_name);        
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageMenuItem);
        ImageButton btnAddToOrder =(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnOrder);

        HashMap<String, String> MenuItem = new HashMap<String, String>();
        MenuItem= data.get(position);
        if(!TempVar.SELECTEDLIST.isEmpty())
        {
            for(String selected:TempVar.SELECTEDLIST){
            if(Integer.toString(position).equals(selected))

             {
                   vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg_hover);
             }
            else
                {
                           vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg);
                }
        }
        }

        textID.setText(MenuItem.get(DBFunctions.TAG_MENU_ITEM_CODE));
        textName.setText((MenuItem.get(DBFunctions.TAG_MENU_ITEM_NAME)).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(MenuItem.get(DBFunctions.TAG_MENU_ITEM_IMAGE_PATH),image);

            btnAddToOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {   @Override
             public void onClick(View v)
                 {
                String qty = textQty.getText().toString();

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map=data.get(position);
                        TempVar.SELECTEDLIST.add(Integer.toString(position));
                HashMap<String, String> order = new HashMap<String, String>();

                order.put(DBFunctions.TAG_MENU_ITEM_CODE,map.get(DBFunctions.TAG_MENU_ITEM_CODE));
                order.put(DBFunctions.TAG_MENU_ITEM_NAME,map.get(DBFunctions.TAG_MENU_ITEM_NAME));
                TempVar.ORDERARRAYLIST.add(order);
                RelativeLayout parent =(RelativeLayout) v.getParent().getParent(); 
                parent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg_hover);

             }



        });


        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: are you cleaning your selected list???

Comment: i clear it at the end of the task and initialize it again at login

Comment: Can you please add the `getView` and `onItemClickListener` code

Comment: do u add notifydatasetchanged?

Comment: @sreekanth where do i call notifydatasetchanged in the onclick??

Comment: @Sreekanthss i have added the code ..the choice mode is set  to multiple

Comment: your getView is looks ok and  add notifydatasetchanged  after adding data in list view..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23199/discussion-between-lubismail-and-sreekanthss)

Comment: i added notify datasetchanged(). Now only the last selected item is highlighted when we reload the activity

Comment: @Archie.bpgc i ve added the codes ..

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop is wrong,try the snapshot below :

```
    if(TempVar.SELECTEDLIST.contains(position))

         {
           vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg_hover);
         }
    else
        {
            vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg);
        }
```

Comment: when i tried this ,it didnt enter the if true case at all..do i have to override equals and hashcode methods?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this code if it works:

```
for(int i = 0;i< yourSelectedList.length;i++){
            if(Integer.toString(position).equals(selected)) {
                   selected = true;
                 }
               }
        if(selected){

                   vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg_hover);
                 }
        else
                {
                    vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg);
                }
```

Comment: it selects all list items below the first selected item.

Answer (score 0):

In `btnAddToOrder.setOnClickListener` of the `getView()` method, you are using

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map = data.get(position);
```

here the **position** is not the position of the **ListViewItem  whose btnAddToOrder** you clicked, it is the position of the newly created **ListViewItem**, which probably is the last or first visible item in the ListView.

Go get the correct position of the ListViewItem whose btnAddToOrder you clicked, use this:

```
final int actualPosition = yourListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map = data.get(actualPosition);
```

in the `btnAddToOrder.setOnClickListener`. where **v** is your **btnAddToOrder**.

Comment: is my listview accessible from my Adapter class?

Comment: data refers to the arraylist<hashmap<String,String> that is obtained from the parameters passed to the Adapter .Am i still wrong?

Comment: Your ListView can be accessible in the AdapterClass if you pass it as a parameter while constructing the Adapter

Comment: i tried this.. thnx fo your help  ..it works same .I  mean i am able to highlight the selected  list item but when i reload the activity no item is highlighted...Any ideas?